# How to find marginal distribution from joint distribution with multi-variable dependence?

Tags: self-study, random-variable, marginal-distribution, joint-distribution

One of the problems in my textbook is posed as follows. A two-dimensional stochastic continuous vector has the following density function:

$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
15xy^2 & \text{if 0 < x < 1 and 0 < y < x}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Show that the marginal density functions $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are:

$$
f_{X}(x)=
\begin{cases}
5x^4 & \text{if 0 < x < 1}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$
f_{Y}(y)=
\begin{cases}
\scriptsize{\frac{15}{2}}\normalsize y^2(1-y^2) & \text{if 0 < y < 1}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$

I understand how the density function $f_X$ is calculated, by integrating $f_{X,Y}$ from $0$ to $x$ with respect to $y$. I'm however totally lost on $f_Y$, where is the $(1-y^2)$ coming from? If I integrate from $0$ to $1$ with respect to $x$ then I only get $\scriptsize{\frac{15}{2}}\normalsize y^2$, and why is the range $0 < y < 1$?

I've graphed the support for $X,Y$, all values where $f_{X,Y}>0$ are colored blue:

[image: The support for $X,Y$]

Comment: It might help you to draw a picture of the support of $(X,Y)$ (which is the set of $(x,y)$ for which $f(x,y)\ne 0$).  That should immediately answer some of your questions.

Comment: @whuber Okay so I've graphed the support and I think I understand why it's 0 < y < 1, it's because x is only defined in 0 < x < 1 and since 0 < y < x we then naturally have that y is only defined from 0 to 1, correct? But I still don't understand the (1-y^2) part.

Comment: Hint: The marginal density of $f_Y(y)$ is the _integral_ of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ which, for a fixed value of $y$, $0 < y < 1$, is nonzero only for those $x$ satisfying $y < x < 1$. That is, $$f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx = \int_y^1 15xy^2 dx$$ and that is where the $(1-y^2)$ part comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Dilip, I'm afraid I don't understand it fully though. ".. for a fixed value of $y$, $0 < y < 1$, is nonzero only for those $x$ satisfying $y<x<1$." Are you referring to the blue area on the chart?

Comment: @soren.qvist Yes. I am referring to the blue area on the chart. $f_Y(0.4)$  is the integral (area under the curve) of a _function_ of $x$ which has value $(15(0.4)^2)x=2.4x$ if $x$ is between $0.4$ and $1$ (the blue area) and $0$ otherwise. Repeat for other _fixed_ values of $y$, and notice that each time the numerical value of $f_Y(y)$ works out to be the same number as obtained by "plugging in" the chosen value of $y$ into the expression $f_Y(y)$ as given in your answer sheet. Then, comes the "Hey Ma, I think I see a pattern!" moment and you realize that $f_Y(y)$ equals the integral shown.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Great, thanks a lot! I think I understand it now.

Comment: @soren.qvist Why don't you do a neat write-up of how you found $f_Y(y)$ based on the above comments and post it as an _answer_ to your own question? You could even accept the answer that you post a little later as the best answer. That way, this question will get off the List of Unanswered Questions and will not get thrown up for consideration by Community wiki as a question that has not received enough attention from the readership of stats.SE

Comment: Which textbook you found this question?

Answer (score 15):

As you correctly pointed out in your question $f_{Y}(y)$ is calculated by integrating the joint density, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ with respect to X. The critical part here is identifying the area on which you integrate. You have already clearly showed graphically the support of the joint distribution function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. So, now, you can note that the range of $X$ in the shaded region is from $X=y$ to $X=1$ (i.e. graphically, you can visualize horizontal lines, parallel to the x-axis,  going from the diagonal line $Y=X$ to the vertical line at $X=1$).

Thus, the lower and upper limits of the integration are going to be $X=y$ and $X=1$. Thus, the solution to the problem is as follows:
$$f_{Y}(y)= \int_{y}^{1} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx= \int_{y}^{1} 15xy^{2} dx=15y^{2}\int_{y}^{1} x dx=15y^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2\Big|_y^1\right)\\=\frac{15}{2}y^2(1-y^2).
$$

Answer (score 1):

The reason for integrating for $f_{XY}(x,y)\,dx$ from the range $y$ to $1$ is that it gives you the $(1-y^2)$ term.
The marginal distribution is when for any constant value of fixed $y$ we sum over all the possible values of $x.$
So here if we fix $y,$ say, at $0.6,$ then $f_{XY}(x,y)\,dx$ has to be integrated for all the values of $x$ in $(-\infty, +\infty).$ But for this case it must also satisfy two more bounding constraints on the random variable $X.$ $X$ should be such that it's greater than $Y$ only when the joint pdf is defined (see your definition of the joint pdf).
Now here I took $0.6$ as the fixed $Y.$
I get
$$f_Y(0.6) = \int_{0.6}^1 f_{XY}(x,y)\,dx.$$
So if we want for any arbitrary value of $y$ then we integrate $x$ from limits $y$ to $1.$

I hope that helps
Cheers